# What's the book that explores emphasis on words in sentences to change the meaning?

Tags: technique, grammar

I'm looking for a book I saw many years ago. The book showed how a sentence could have different meanings, depending where you placed the emphasis. To indicate the emphasis, the book put a dot above a particular word.

It's a technique I'd like to use in a book myself.

If you're familiar with the book, do you know it's title? Otherwise,  do you know of an alternative resource or topic on this technique?

For example, in the sentence "I never said she stole my money", if you stress a different word each time you read it the meaning changes. Try it, it's cool.

Comment: An I right that you mean emphasizing _that word_, or do you mean changing emphasis within the word; i.e. emphasizing a different syllable?

Comment: I've seen these as studies for actors. You could look there.

Comment: @KaiMaxfield Please see my edit. It's stress on a word, rather than syllable, although that technique also sounds interesting.

Comment: If you're talking about spoken emphasis, I'm not sure how this is a writing question? (In general, we try to avoid "find me that book" or "find me a resource on--" questions; they fit poorly into our Q&A structure.) So if you could clarify what it is, exactly, you're trying to get done (and where you're having trouble!), that'd be very helpful.

Comment: If the book demonstrates how to portray tonal inflections and/or word emphasis in text, I would love to get my hands on it.

Comment: @KaiMaxfield You could use italics.Boldface maybe. I am one of the ones who like to include regional or cultural renderings in my character's dialogue.

Comment: @Gandalf Yeah, I thought about that right after I posted the comment, but I guess the reasoning is that a whole book devoted to expression of this sort would have to go deeper than italics, although I'm not sure how...

Comment: Just a thought. If the emphasis is on a specific word, the word could be changed to some slang, in this case *money*. “I want my money” could be changed to: “I want my beacon you owe me!” which could be changed to: “You better throw me my bones.”

Answer (score 2):

This is called the [*accentual function of prosody*.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosody_%28linguistics%29). I know a book that describes this- **English Phonetics and Phonology (Cambridge 2009)** but I also pasted a link to Wiki on the definition.

Comment: That's a great resource Gandalf, but not the book that I've seen in the past. If it helps anyone, the book is small and concise, maybe not even a 100 pages and is filled with examples that grow in increasing difficulty. This is more the theoretical underpinning of this concept and more.

Comment: I used to do accent neutralization in Latin America and Asia. Surprisingly, that example you used is popular in India in Bangalore Call Centers. I'll look through my old presentations and workbooks and try to find if they leave a reference.